# Set image based on data in getView() method

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

`Index`,`Gainers`,`Losers` are the 3 `buttons`.
On each `button` click, `listView` gets populated with corresponding data.

3rd column `%Chg` can be *negative* or *positive*.

Based on value of `%Chg` value, corresponding `arrow` should be displayed in `imageView` placed after `%Chg` column value i.e. *up arrow* for *positive value* and *down arrow* for *negative value* ...

On any `button` click, I'm passing value of `%Chg` column in an array named `updown` to `Adapter` class

Based on that value, `Adapter` should set the *`down arrow`* or *`up arrow`*

**Code snippet from Adapter class(getView() method)**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_table, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.SecondText);
            holder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ThirdText);
            holder.ivarrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivarrow);
            holder.l1 = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
//Setting the row background
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            try {
                InputStream is1 = ctx.getAssets().open("cellbg.png");
                Drawable d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(is1, "cellbg");
                holder.l1.setBackgroundDrawable(d1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Error(" exception in TableListAdapter "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                InputStream is2 = ctx.getAssets().open("cellbg1.png");
                Drawable d2 = Drawable.createFromStream(is2, "cellbg1");
                holder.l1.setBackgroundDrawable(d2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Error(" exception in TableListAdapter "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        count++;
//setting the arrow
        if (i < updown.length) {
            if (updown[i] > 0) {
                holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                Log.v("up", "up");
            } else {
                holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                Log.v("down", "down");
            }
            Log.v("i=", i + " ,updown=" + updown[i]);
            i++;
        }

        holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        holder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        return convertView;
    }
```

.

Log is showing correct data but **arrow is getting displayed in only 1st row**. i.e. if Last value of list is `positive`, it shows `up arrow` to 1st row and if Last value of list is `negative`, it shows `down arrow` to 1st row...

**How to display corresponding arrow to each row??**

I'm new to android development. So *ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!*
.

[image: screen]

Comment: Post your full getview method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (i < updown.length) {
        if (updown[i] > 0) 
            holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
        else 
            holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
        Log.v("i=", i + " ,updown=" + updown[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

replace your code with :

```
if (updown[position] > 0) 
            holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
        else 
            holder.ivarrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
```

And I think it Works for you